# Which .NET library has copy-on-write collections?

Tags: c#, .net

I am searching for .NET copy-on-write collections to use in C# programs, such as List, Dictionary, etc. Which collections have that property?

Answer (score 17):

Include the reference `FSharp.Core`. And then you have access to many kinds of collections which is immutable (`Set`, `List`, `Map` etc.)

These are located in `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections`.

Example:

```
var map = MapModule.Empty<string, int>();
var newMap = map.Add("key", 1);
```

You probably want to define some extension methods so you can call directly on `map`.

**Update:** The BCL team is working on immutable collections as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023943/174574) which makes this partly obsolete. F# collections can still be used, but BCL collections have a more C# feel to them.

Direct link to Nuget package: [Immutable Collections](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable)

Comment: I'm curious about your library, but unfortunately "Not found - The page you are looking for does not exist."

Comment: @mbx Yes, my webhost failed. I'm working on getting it online again :/

Answer (score 9):

.NET just shipped their first [copy-on-write collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx), which I suggest you try out.

Comment: New version: [Update to Immutable Collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/03/06/update-to-immutable-collections.aspx)